# CakePHP 3.x redirect to pages with no params

Tags: cakephp

In CakePHP 3.x how can I redirect all pages with any params, such as:

```
https://.../controller/action?xxx=aaa
```

directly to pages with no params (I'd like to have no params in URLs):

```
https://.../controller/action
```

The question realates to make it for the whole website.

Comment: What server are you using? Apache? Nginx?

Comment: Apache, but I would like to have such redirect made in CakePHP, not on server

Comment: Why would you like to perform this in CakePHP rather than .htaccess?

Comment: Client's demand